# Convergent series and divergent series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^3+1}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2+1}{n^3+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hi I have two questions.

First, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^3+1}$.

Is it divergent or convergent? I think it seems like it is positive and decreasing function so we can apply integral test. however, integrating this function is not an easy task.

Is there any other test I can use?

Second, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2+1}{n^3+1}$.

I can't think of any test,,

Can anyone give me an idea please~

Comment: Don't the terms in the first sum resemble $1/n^2$? And in the second sum, don't they resemble $1/n$?

Comment: So for the first one I can use comparison test so that 1/n^2 is greater than that and is convergent and it must be converegent

Comment: for the second part I think I could use comparison test but can't see which  one shall I use

Answer (score 5):

A great starting point on these questions is to "ignore all the small pieces" and see what happens. For instance, for large $n$, the $+1$ in the denominators won't really matter. So the first really looks like
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}$$
and the second looks like
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n}.$$
Some calculus books have a so-called "limit comparison" test that makes this analysis rigorous. Barring that, let's see if we can do better.

In the first,
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n}{n^3 + 1} < \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n}{n^3} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

In the second, $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n^2 + 1}{n^3 + 1} > \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n^2}{n^3 + n^3} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n \geq 1}  \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: for the second part, how can I show that n^2/n^3+n^3 is less than n^2+1/n^3+1?

Comment: I made the numerator smaller and the denominator bigger.

Comment: Thanks makes a lot sense to me